# Typo3 major upgrade version from 9.5 to 10.4

Tags: composer-php, migration, typo3

I have some problems updating the extensions from typo3(9.5 to 10.4) with composer. I followed the documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/master/enus/Upgrade/InstallTheNewSource/Index.html, however, I'm using some extensions that require typo3 (9.5) version. What should I do with those ? should I remove them from composer.json and looked for other alternatives ?

This is a sample error while trying to update typo3 packages

```
 Problem 7
- gridelementsteam/gridelements is locked to version 9.7.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
- gridelementsteam/gridelements 9.7.0 requires typo3/cms-backend ^9.5.7 -> found typo3/cms-backend[v9.5.7, ..., v9.5.28] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^10.4).
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to use the --update-with-all-dependencies option and/or also require the packages which are not compatible with 9.5 e.g. `composer req typo3/cms-core:^9.5 typo3/cms-backend:^9.5 .... gridelementsteam/gridelements:^10 ...`

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? If you use incompatible packages, you either need to update them or remove them

Comment: You've ignored the part "If you have extensions installed, find the corresponding newer versions you want to install for your new major version, and update them too."...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if there are newer versions of the extensions that cause problems. If it's just gridelements, there is a version that's compatible with TYPO3 10.4. You should upgrade that extension to version 10.2 in your composer.json. Then you should check if everything still works. Extensions sometimes have breaking changes, though I think gridelements shouldn't have any problems in this case.

If there are more extensions and they don't have newer versions that are compatible with TYPO3 10.4 you have multiple options:

- Remove them and look for alternatives
- Contact the creator of the extensions and ask if they can make it compatible to TYPO3 10.4 (or already have a version they haven't released)
- Make the extensions compatible yourself of have someone else do it

Answer (score 0):

The extensions which are not supported for TYPO3 10 version you need to remove them and look for alternative.
But as for the gridelements extension it's available for TYPO3 10.4. You need to update in your composer.json gridelements version from 9.7.0 to 10.2.0.
You can look into the https://extensions.typo3.org to see if an extension is updated for TYPO3 10 or not.
Gridelements is available for TYPO3 10.4.
here is extension page for  Gridelements https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/gridelements/

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update these extensions. Except you do not really need it.
if you only need a newer version and it's available you might change the version restriction in your composer.json.

Maybe a newer Version is not available at the same origin, then you need to change repository information to get the newer version from the other place.

Some extensions are still not ready for TYPO3 10, but have a developer branch to test the work with TYPO3 10. You have to adapt your composer.json line to get a developer-version instead of a stable (maybe combined with another repository.